# How do i run a Jasmine test for a specific browser?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

In my project, I have some functions that detect what browser is currently used. I would like to test them automatically using Jasmine tests.

How do I run one specific test in a selected browser?

browser-detection.ts:

```
export class BrowserDetection {
    public static isMicrosoftInternetExplorer() {
        return this.isBrowser('MSIE ');
    }

    public static isMicrosoftEdge() {
        return this.isBrowser('Edge/')
    }

    public static isGoogleChrome() {
        return this.isBrowser('chrome');
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param browserString Browserstring as it is found in the useragent string.
     * @returns {boolean} Returns true if there is a match for the browserstring.
     */
    private static isBrowser(browserString): boolean {
        let userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
        return userAgent.indexOf(browserString) >= 0;
    }
}
```

browser-detection.spec.ts:

```
import {BrowserDetection} from "app/module/browser-detection/browser-detection";

describe('BrowserDetection', () => {
    it('detects google chrome correctly', () => {
        // Arrange
        // TODO: only run this test on google chrome

        // Act
        let result = BrowserDetection.isGoogleChrome();

        // Assert
        expect(result).toBe(true);
    })
});
```

Comment: Another note: this test is failing in google chrome, because isBrowser() incorrectly returns false when i run "ng test". isBrowser() does return the correct boolean when we actually run the program with "ng serve".

Answer (score 1):

It can get full coverage with unit tests.

At first `isBrowser` can be stubbed and browser-specific methods can be tested:

```
spyOn(BrowserDetection, 'isBrowser');

BrowserDetection.isBrowser.and.returnValue(true);
expect(BrowserDetection.isGoogleChrome()).toBe(true);

BrowserDetection.isBrowser.and.returnValue(false);
expect(BrowserDetection.isGoogleChrome()).toBe(false);

expect(BrowserDetection.isBrowser).toHaveBeenCalledWith('chrome');
```

Then `isBrowser` can be tested against real UA string, because `navigator.userAgent` cannot be stubbed.

```
expect(BrowserDetection.isBrowser(navigator.userAgent)).toBe(true);
expect(BrowserDetection.isBrowser(navigator.userAgent.slice(5, -5))).toBe(true);
expect(BrowserDetection.isBrowser('foo')).toBe(false);
expect(BrowserDetection.isBrowser(navigator.userAgent + 'foo')).toBe(false);
```

Alternatively, `BrowserDetection`can be a service (static-only class is antipattern any way) that uses another service, `window`, This way `window` and it's properties could be mocked in tests and provide fake UA string.

Comment: These are some good tests to run on this file. However, what I would like to do is run isGoogleChrome() and check if it is true if the test is running in Google Chrome, using the real window.navigator.userAgent.

Comment: When the class is covered with unit tests like is shown above, you don't need to do functional test with real UA string. That's what unit tests are for. You can do `if (/chrome/i.test(navigator.userAgent) { it(...) }` too, but it is redundant.